# Slicing and dicing images for Google Play

Tags: image, makefile, make

Making an Android app involves making a lot of images of various sizes:

- The app's launcher icon, in high/low/medium resolution
- Buttons, menu buttons, if any, in high/low/medium resolution
- Images for listing on Google Play: main icon, feature graphics

To simplify this, I use high-resolution source images
+ ImageMagick to cut to the various sizes
+ Makefile to only regenerate the images whose source image has changed.

For the feature graphics I cheat:
I just generate a transparent canvas with the required dimensions,
and overlay on top of it the app's icon, as big as it fits.

```
src_dir:=src
hdpi_dir:=res/drawable-hdpi
ldpi_dir:=res/drawable-ldpi
mdpi_dir:=res/drawable-mdpi

names:=$(patsubst $(src_dir)/%,%,$(wildcard $(src_dir)/*.png $(src_dir)/*.jpg))
hdpi_target:=$(patsubst %,$(hdpi_dir)/%,$(names))
ldpi_target:=$(patsubst %,$(ldpi_dir)/%,$(names))
mdpi_target:=$(patsubst %,$(mdpi_dir)/%,$(names))

appicon:=googleplay/appicon.png
feature:=googleplay/feature.png
canvas:=googleplay/canvas.png
work:=googleplay/work.png

default: all

hdpi: $(hdpi_dir) $(hdpi_target)

ldpi: $(ldpi_dir) $(ldpi_target)

mdpi: $(mdpi_dir) $(mdpi_target)

googleplay: $(appicon) $(feature)

all: hdpi ldpi mdpi googleplay

clean: 
    rm $(hdpi_target) $(ldpi_target) $(mdpi_target) $(appicon) $(feature)

$(hdpi_dir):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(ldpi_dir):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(mdpi_dir):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(hdpi_dir)/btn_%.png: $(src_dir)/btn_%.png
    convert -geometry 48x $< $@
    identify $@

$(ldpi_dir)/btn_%.png: $(src_dir)/btn_%.png
    convert -geometry 24x $< $@
    identify $@

$(mdpi_dir)/btn_%.png: $(src_dir)/btn_%.png
    convert -geometry 36x $< $@
    identify $@

$(hdpi_dir)/launcher_%.png: $(src_dir)/launcher_%.png
    convert -geometry 72x $< $@
    identify $@

$(ldpi_dir)/launcher_%.png: $(src_dir)/launcher_%.png
    convert -geometry 36x $< $@
    identify $@

$(mdpi_dir)/launcher_%.png: $(src_dir)/launcher_%.png
    convert -geometry 48x $< $@
    identify $@

$(appicon): $(src_dir)/launcher_main.png
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    convert -geometry 512x $< $@
    identify $@

$(feature): $(src_dir)/launcher_main.png
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    convert -size 1024x500 xc:transparent $(canvas)
    convert -geometry 1024x500 $< $(work)
    convert -composite $(canvas) $(work) -gravity west $@
    identify $@
```

If you want to play with this,
save this script as `Makefile`,
put an image file in `src/launcher_main.png`,
and assuming you have ImageMagick installed,
simply run `make` to have the images of various sizes generated in the `res` directory.
In Android projects I have `res` pointing to the real resources directory of the project.

This works well, but it's a bit repetitive at some places.
I'm wondering if this can be more DRY,
or if there are other ways to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use target- and pattern-specific variables:

```
$(ldpi_dir)/btn_%.png : GEOMETRY := 24x
$(mdpi_dir)/btn_%.png : GEOMETRY := 36x
$(hdpi_dir)/btn_%.png : GEOMETRY := 72x
```

and similar definitions for `launcher_%.png`

Then you can combine all the individual recopies into a single one:

```
$(ldpi_dir)/%.png $(mdpi_dir)/%.png $(hdpi_dir)/%.png) :
    convert -geometry $(GEOMETRY) $< $@
    identify $@
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I can't get this to work. Can you please include a more complete example?

Comment: Also, the `)` at the end of `$(ldpi_dir)/%.png $(mdpi_dir)/%.png $(hdpi_dir)/%.png) ` is a typo right?